# Remove the title bar but keep the control box?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm overriding the CreateParams property in my form to draw a custom oversized titlebar:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        CreateParams.Style = CInt(CreateParams.Style And Not &HC00000L) 'WS_CAPTION
    End Get
End Property
```

And I've overridden WndProc to allow the form to be dragged:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)

    If m.Msg = &H84 AndAlso m.Result.ToInt32() = 1 Then m.Result = New IntPtr(2)
End Sub
```

But the control box (close and minimize) disappears. Is there any way to keep the control box and the text in the taskbar, but remove the usual title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to hide the title (and maybe the icon) from the titlebar, but not from the taskbar, just like the Vista/7 Explorer window.

This should help you:
[MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/6b5561a0-3e20-425a-a723-2fd7c9850010/)
Use [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with your preferred WTA_OPTIONS (should be 0x03) in pvAttribute.

Comment: This only works if DWM composition is enabled. You have to include code to handle things differently if it's disabled (or if the user is running on Windows XP).

Comment: Oh, sorry that i forgot to say that. It is an aero-only (also aero basic) feature.

Answer (score 1):

Once you elect to draw the non-client area yourself, you have to draw it all. There are no hybrid options.

Answer (score 0):

You overrode the creation parameters to get a window *without* a title bar.  Implementing support for WM_NCHITTEST was correct, there wouldn't be another way for the user to move the window around.

You don't have to override CreateParams to get this behavior.  Just set the ControlBox property to False, the Text property to an empty string.  What you want is hard to guess.  If you don't want to lose the buttons on the title bar then just don't set ControlBox to False.  "Unusual title" is very hard to guess too, what you see there is just the value of the Text property.  Set it to an empty string if you don't want a title.

Comment: I want the text to display in the taskbar, so setting Text to an empty string won't work. Of course I want to keep the control box, I said so in my question, so why would I set Controlbox to False?? I think you misunderstood - I override the creation parameters to remove the title bar so I can draw my own title bar, with images and custom fonts.

Comment: Well, then you only have to draw whatever title you want by overriding the form's OnPaint() method.  You can make it look just the way you want it, no need for it to look weird.  You'll have to also draw your own glyphs for the minimize and close buttons, e.Graphics.DrawImage in the OnPaint() method will do that.  And you have to do hit-testing in the OnMouseDown override so you can see the user trying to click your buttons.  Or use a regular Button.

Comment: I want to keep the control box (close & minimize).

Comment: Sigh, you can't.  You don't have a title bar anymore.  There's no place for Windows to put them.  You can't tell it to put them somewhere else.

Comment: And that's what I was verifying - but I'm sure there's a way. And someone else might have posted the answer! I just can't test it yet, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Hans is right. Just draw them yourself manually (or create them as buttons) and add the appropriate events for them. Much quicker than overcomplifying things...

Comment: Well, I want to keep to the general Windows theme, animations and all, and there's practically no way I can do that myself. This project doesn't merit that kind of effort.

Comment: why on earth do you want to do anything other than let the system draw it all for you?